# CD Ripping in Delphi

Tags: delphi, cd

Is there any example how to rip audio cd in delphi?

Answer (score 2):

Commercial ActiveX, US$150:
[CD Extractor Control](http://www.streamware-dev.com/products.html#extractor)

DLL, Free for freeware, 50 Euros for use in shareware:
[Bass CD Ripper](http://www.3delite.hu/Object%20Pascal%20Developer%20Resources/basscdripperlibrary.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to accomplish the task, then you could consider running an existing command line tool to perform the CD rip (i.e. spawning this task from your delphi code)